# WordPress Media Uploader thumbnails option

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

in WordPress you can create Media Library popup by calling wp.media() function, this works fine but the problem is that there's no option to choose image size(thumbnails) of selected image. Is there a way to add support for thumbnail selection ?
I'm using WordPress 4.5.2, code sample:

```
wp.media.frames.selectFile=wp.media(
{
    multiple        :   false
});
```

Thanks for help !

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is function in WordPress  `wp_generate_attachment_metadata()`

Example: `<?php wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id, $file ); ?>`

Comment: Little misunderstanding, I don't want to register new thumbnail size, but to add size selector dropdown field to the media upload window. Screenshot: http://imgur.com/FRXrMuA (Example window that we get after clicking 'Add Media' button).